# A mecca with bling

Tags: riddle, knowledge, geography, history

> One word my city, it ends with a king;
>   two words my own name, a mecca with bling.
>   Three old trees decorate my hallowed doors,
>   four walls of aurum, a pool and two floors.
>   Five times nine decades since I came to be;
>   six are the people who venerate me.

What am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are

> [Golden Temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Temple) or Sri Harmandir Sahib

One word my city, it ends with a king;

> Amritsar ends with 'tsar' which means emperor of Russia. 
>  (I'm sorry for not noticing the letter 't' and thanks @M Oehm for pointing it out)

two words my own name, a mecca with bling.

> The name is two word, Golden Temple, and it's a heart of the Sikh just like mecca is to Islam. That brings us to, Mecca(temple) with a bling(golden).

Three old trees decorate my hallowed doors,

> This refers to three [Ber trees](http://www.sikh-history.com/sikhhist/images/gurdwaras/ber_baba_buddha.jpg) near the hollowed entrance of the the two storey courtyard. (Ber Baba Buddha, Laachi Ber and Dukh Bhanjani Ber)

four walls of aurum, a pool and two floors.

> In that order, the golden temple itself, the sacred pool, and the two storey courtyard. (Aurum is Latin for 'gold').

Five times nine decades since I came to be;

> The construction started in 1581.

six are the people who venerate me.

> It is the holiest and the most important pilgrimage site of Sikhism. Six is a wordplay on 'Sikh'.

Comment: That must be it! (Amritsar literally ends with "tsar" and I guess six sounds like Sikhs.)

Comment: Yep! That's what I think too. I am pretty sure about the 'six' part, but not at all on the 'tsar' part.

Comment: Why not? It doesn't say anywhere that the king must have a connection to the Golden Temple or that Amritsar was named for a king. And I guess it says "king" rather than "emperor" just for the rhyme.

Comment: Try taking 4 letters instead of 3...

Comment: @jafe That's what M Oehm was trying to point out to me ("literally" ends with "tsar"). God, I'm so dumb. haha! I'm sorry for not noticing that.

Comment: Tick goes to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Partial:

One word my city, it ends with a king;
two words my own name, a mecca with bling.

> [Saint Augustine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Augustine,_Florida) The oldest city in the US of European origin.
>  King... reference to [Augustus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augustus)

Three old trees decorate my hallowed doors,

> I got nothing here. There has to be one of the points of interest [in here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Augustine,_Florida#Points_of_interest)

four walls of aurum, a pool and two floors.

> Same as above
>  ... and pool = [Fountain of Youth Archaeological Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fountain_of_Youth_Archaeological_Park)

Five times nine decades since I came to be;

> The city was established on September 8, 1565 453 years ago, (about 4 * 5 * 10).

six are the people who venerate me.

> Still looking fot his one.

Comment: This is a surprisingly good fit (especially line 5), but not the intended answer.

Comment: I figured is not the intended answer when I saw that after 15 minutes of searching I got nothing on the last line.